# My jQuery functions does not get applied to the element when inside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dimensions array -

```
var dimensions = [
{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 680,
    "height": 294.75
},
{
    "x": 680,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 680,
    "height": 294.75
},
{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 294.75,
    "width": 680,
    "height": 294.75
},
{
    "x": 680,
    "y": 294.75,
    "width": 680,
    "height": 294.75
}
]
```

window Properties function that creates window

```
function windowProperties(containment, x, y, width, height) { //New Window Style and jQuery Functions

  $(containment).append('<div id="window' + divCount + '"><p id="windowName' + divCount + '"></p><p id="para' + divCount + '">Source</p></div>');
  nWindow = document.getElementById('window' + divCount);
  paragraph = document.getElementById('para' + divCount);
  windowName = document.getElementById('windowName' + divCount)

  paragraph.style.color = "black";
  paragraph.style.fontSize = "20px";
  paragraph.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  paragraph.style.padding = "20px";
  paragraph.style.textAlign = "center";

  windowName.style.color = "black";
  windowName.style.fontSize = "20px";
  windowName.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  windowName.style.padding = "10px";
  windowName.style.textAlign = "center";
  windowName.innerHTML = 'Window ' + divCount;

  nWindow.style.width = width + "px"; //680
  nWindow.style.position = "absolute";
  nWindow.style.height = height + "px"; //294.75
  nWindow.style.opacity = "0.5";
  nWindow.style.background = "white";
  nWindow.style.zIndex = "200";
  nWindow.style.top = y + "px";
  nWindow.style.left = x + "px";

  $(function() {

    $.fn.getPosition = function() {
      var results = $(this).position();
      results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
      results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
      return results;
    }

    $(nWindow).resizable({
      maxWidth: 1356,
      maxHeight: 585.5,
      grid: [3, 4],
      aspectRatio: true,
    });

    $(nWindow).draggable({
      cursor: "move",
      snapTolerance: '20',
      snap: nWindow,
      containment: '.videoWallContainer',
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());

      }

    });

    $(sources).draggable({
      cursor: "pointer",
      helper: "clone",
      appendTo: nWindow,

    });

    $(nWindow).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      accept: sources,
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(paragraph).text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(nWindow);
        console.log(nWindow);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Creating all elements at once

```
var createAllWindows = document.getElementById('createAllWindows').onclick = function() { //All window creation button
  var i = 0;
  while (i < dimensions.length) {
    dimensions.forEach(function(size) {
      i++;
      console.log("Window " + i);
      console.log(size.x);
      console.log(size.y);
      console.log(size.width);
      console.log(size.height);
      windowProperties(container, size.x, size.y, size.width, size.height); //Calling function
      divCount++;
    });
  }
};
```

When the windows are created in respective positions of the array, the loop creates them but doesnt apply the jQuery function to the window even tho it is inside the called function. am i doing soemthing wrong?

Comment: Declare your variables as local with `var`.

Comment: Which variables?

Comment: All of them, but the one you need is `nWindow`.

Comment: Oh it works now! Thanks!